# Best way to share events in Meteor.JS

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

What is the best way to share event handlers in Meteor?

Is it by having one big template that wraps over the template? Or is it by creating a JS class and grabbing the event handler from tehre?

i.e.
Option 1

```
<template name="wrap">
  {{>tmpl1}}
</template>
<template name="wrap">
  {{>tmpl2}}
</template>
```

and then put events in template "wrap"

or...

Option2

```
Template.tmpl1.events({
  event1: function(e,t){ some_class.event1(e,t) }
})
Template.tmpl2.events({
  event1: function(e,t){ some_class.event1(e,t) }
})
```

some_class has the events and templates just call from them

Which of these two is the best way? And is there a better way than this?

Comment: Try using the Template.registerHelper function to define a global template helper. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper

Answer (score 0):

I've used 3 different patterns in my app.

1. Your first one: define event handlers on an outer template, for example in my default layout template. This is particularly well suited to things like keyboard events that are often reused.
2. The second one: define a small template that has the object and the events I need and reuse that everywhere (for example, a button)
3. Use [dynamic templates](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic) and define events on the container template. This is essentially a more flexible version of your first pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `Dynamic Templates`:

```
<template name="wrap">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=yourTemplate }}
</template>
```

You can then make a `Session` variable that changes `yourTemplate` out as you wish and the correct template will display.  If you're using something like `iron-router` you can specify that template to change per route:

```
Router.map(function () {

  this.route('myEventTest', {
    path: '/route-1',
    template: 'wrap',
    data: function () {
      return {
        yourTemplate: 'tmpl1' // the template you want changed
      };
    }
  });

  this.route('myEventTest', {
    path: '/route-2',
    template: 'wrap',
    data: function () {
      return {
        yourTemplate: 'tmpl2'
      };
    }
  });

});
```

And then make the event map for your `wrap` template.

```
Template.wrap.events({
  'click .element-in-either-template': function () {
    console.log('okay');
  }
});
```